# temp/tmp directory cannot be configured for a custom location

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Sonarqube installed in `/opt/sonar`

I configured in `/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties`

```
sonar.path.temp=/data/sonar/temp
```

As a result after restarting Sonarqube there is a directory `/data/sonar/temp` that includes a dir `"tc"` and a file `"sharedmemory"` and so on.

But after a couple of seconds there is also the standard temp dir in `/opt/sonar` that includes the `tmp` dir.

Is it possible to move the complete temp folder to a custom location?

Thanks in advance,

Steffen

Comment: What's the content of /opt/sonar/tmp ?

Comment: It's not /opt/sonar/tmp.
The directory temp that I configured to appear in /data/sonar/temp (because there is more disk space) after the restart of Sonarqube appears in the default location /opt/sonar/temp as well.
In /opt/sonar/temp is a directory tmp which includes a lot of dat files for all the issues that occur during the analysis.

This directory get big after a while, therefore I would like it to appear in /data/sonar/temp as I configured it. But this doesn't work.